# Select one of two distinct boolean values

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-2017-express

I have a column that is a bit. I want to update all the records to `1` if `1` is present in that column.

When the query runs and there are no `1` in the column it returns `0` as I expect. If it is all `1` it returns just `1` as I expect. However, if there is a `1` and a `0` in the column, the distinct returns a `0` and `1`. I understand why, as these are both distinct values.

I want to be able to only select the 1 where 1 is present.

```
UPDATE u    
SET ChannelType = (SELECT DISTINCT ChannelType FROM Staging.UriData WHERE SerialNumber = s.SerialNumber AND ChannelType IS NOT NULL),
Calculated = (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CASE WHEN Calculated = 1
                                        THEN 1  
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END AS BIT  
                            )FROM Staging.UriData WHERE SerialNumber = s.Serialnumber AND Calculated IS NOT NULL)
FROM [Staging].[UriData] u
INNER JOIN #Serial15 s ON u.SerialNumber = s.SerialNumber
WHERE u.ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM [Staging].[ActiveChannels])
AND u.SerialNumber = s.SerialNumber
```

The expected result is that if a `1` is present in the column, I want the `CASE` part of the query, to return `1` and not both distinct values.

I can't provide a dataset in Fiddle as it is part of larger query that contains sensitive information, so apologies in advance.

TIA

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `SELECT DISTINCT`, use `SELECT MAX()`. If there are any `1` values, the result will be `1`, otherwise it will be `0`. i.e.

```
Calculated = (SELECT CAST(MAX(Calculated) AS BIT) 
              FROM Staging.UriData
              WHERE SerialNumber = s.Serialnumber AND Calculated IS NOT NULL)
```